# minimum absolute difference between two numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given two arrays, A and B, i want to find a number from A and a number from B, such that the absolute difference between the two numbers  is the smallest.

Eg

```
A = 1 2 9
B=  4 5  6
```

Ans : 2,4 as Math.abs(2-4) =2

Comment: What programming language? If it doesn't matter, use code golf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort the two arrays, then iterate them in parallel:  For each item in `A`, search the closest item in `B` by a linear search.  Start the linear search in `B` where you stopped for the previous item of `A`.  Always remember the minimal distance found so far.

The time complexity is O(m log m + n log n) for sorting and O(m + n) for the final search, where m and n are the respective lengths of `A` and `B`.

Comment: suppose arrays are (10,11,14) (4,6,8) in this case don't you yours wil be an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: If the arrays are already sorted, you might want to use binary search.

Comment: @Algorithmist: No, the search will be O(m+n), since you always pick up where you stopped last time.  The example you gave would even allow for an early-out, since you will consume all of `B` for the first item in `A`, so you don't have to look any further.

Comment: @phimuemue: I think a linear search is adequate here -- the search part will only have complexity O(m + n), whereas a binary search would be O(n log m).  You can stop searching `B` as soon as the distance from the currently considered item of `A` would increase again.

Answer (score 5):

it could be done in O(nlogm + mlogm)=O(nlogm):

(m is the smallest array`s length)

 assume B is the smaller array

```
sort array B
minimum =  | A[0]-B[0] | 
for each a in A:
binary search for a in B - return the closest numbers let the numbers be b1,b2 (*)
if min{|b1-a|,|b2-a|} is smaller then the previous minimum - store it as the new minimum
```

(*) binary search stops when you are closest to the number (or finds it if it exists)

 checking first which is smaller (A or B) will ensure better performance.-

Answer (score 0):

check this, maybe it gives you an idea so you adapt it to your needs:

```
#define TOP 2147483647
#define true 1
#define false 0


/* finds the minimum (absolute value) of vector vec */

void Vector_Min_Not_0(vector *vec, int *min, int *index)
{
  int m, size, i, ind, aux;

  size = vec->size;
  m = TOP;
  ind = -1;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (vec->p[i] != 0)
      if (m > (aux = abs(vec->p[i]))) {
    ind = i;
    m = aux;
      }
  if (ind == -1)
    *min = 1;
  else
    *min = m;
  *index = ind;
}
```

you would call it, having a structure:

```
typedef struct vector {
  int size;
  int *p;
} vector;

vector vec_A;
int min, index, *p;
Vector_Min_Not_0(&vec_A, &min, &index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that the numbers in the Array will be floats. In Ruby :

```
def smaller_abs(array1, array2)
  array1.product(array2).each_with_index do |ar,i|
      if i==0
        dif = (ar[0]-ar[1]).abs
        pair = ar
        next
      end
      pair = (ar[0]-ar[1]).abs > dif ? pair : ar
  end
  pair
end
```

I am not an algorithm guru but that must work (haven't checked out). Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort both arrays
2. Combine the two numbers using some tag to differentiate them.
   e.g A = 1 9 2 B= 5 4 6

After sorting:

A = 1 2 9 B= 4 5 6

Combine the array: C = 1a 2a 4b 5b 6b 9a

Now do a linear search and find the difference between the consecutive terms with different tag.
Ans: 2a 4b.